# Setting up Ubuntu in VirtualBox connecting to Windows 7 and the Internet

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, setup, virtualbox

I've installed the latest VirtualBox 4.1.2 and Ubuntu Server 11.04.

After playing around with the network settings, I found there's no IP address configured for eth1 and eth2. I think I used to have eth0.

[image]

Network reads:

```
Adapter 1: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop(Host-only adapter, "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter")  
Adapter 2: Intel Pro/1000 T Server (NAT)
```

How should I setup VirtualBox and Ubuntu so that I can access it as a guest from Windows 7? Ubuntu should also be able to access the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the setting of nat for the nics in virtualbox.  This should allow you to access the internet through your host pc.  If I understand what you mean by "guest" (you want to be able to ssh into the vm, and access its server processes as a client from windows7) you want to use bridged-networking.  This will setup a network you can use to communicate between host and guest.

Just to be clear, set the nics as nat and make sure you can access the internet.  When that is working, shutdown the vm, and change nic2 to use bridged networking.  ifconfig eth0 and ifconfig eth1 should show you different networks.

Comment: what is the difference between a bridged network and a virtual host only network? i tried to create a bridged network, but i lost my internet connection.